# You are kinda Replacable to Me

Tags: code-golf, math, number

You are provided with a non-empty array \$A\$ of integers, all greater than 0. But what good is an array if the elements do not sum up to the number \$N\$ (also provided as input)...

So to change that, you can pick any integer of your choice present in the array and replace any of its digits with a different digit between 0-9 of your choice. What is the **minimum** number of digits that you should replace so that the sum of the elements becomes \$N\$?

Note that after replacing the digits, some of the numbers may contain leading zeroes, which is fine. For example: you can change \$123\$ to \$023\$, or even \$000\$ if you want to. However, the input will not contain any leading zeroes and you cannot assume any before the input number.

## Example

Consider the array \$A=[195, 95]\$ and \$N = 380\$. You can do the following replacements:

1. 1**9**5 -> 1**8**5
2. 18**5** -> 18**1**
3. **1**81 -> **2**81
4. 9**5**  -> 9**9**

So the new array is \$A=[281,99]\$ with a sum of \$380\$ in 4 steps. However, this is not minimal and you can do it in even fewer steps:

1. **1**95 -> **2**95
2. **9**5 -> 85

So we got our desired sum in 2 steps. There is no way to get a sum of \$380\$ in less than 2 steps so the answer for \$A=[195, 95]\$ and \$N = 380\$ will be \$2\$.

## More examples

```
  A, N -> Answer
[195, 95], 380 -> 2
[100, 201], 0 -> 3
[32, 64], 96 -> 0
[7, 1, 1], 19 -> 2
[100, 37], 207 -> 1
[215], 25 -> 2
[123, 456], 1998 -> 6
```

## Rules

- Standard loopholes are forbidden.
- You do not need to handle inputs for which answer does not exist.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code, in bytes, wins.

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <sup><s>95</s>…</sup> 93 bytes

```hs
a#n|s<-show=minimum[sum[1|(x,y)<-s a`zip`s b,x/=y]|b<-mapM(mapM(:s(56^7)))a,n==sum(read<$>b)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY/hToMwFIX/8xTNZkKblYx2AsLo/ptofIAGt@Jwa4RCVoxg9uziLc6kbW6@e869p2dlP6q6nia1NFebB/bcfolGG918NtLCZVc80JFAB6nDt@4OFpV0WIuxuJZ50KjuGc9PZnEUvyaEEEWNEGDFl0od87tdSYqpUdqIY@shhDXdZ/usdRM7ZfBa@IFPQHaq@idtKpDUVY@wmmUlEf@qwif61hyEiwmeeQVWq9WiWJAsk4@mL8jWCIdRuR3/Cre2u2jT42EJ0UY6UANfAupiTZKlEUVpVFC0eQhRsEPckxtOUXwPKI0dCT2ZUMTgAGLpTcTCEDwJIB4mjjFPcuYG8WiW/Ly91@pkp@CF/wI)

The relevant function is `(#)`, which takes as input the array `a` and the integer `n` and returns the minimum number of moves. Elements of `a` are represented as strings of digits.

### How?

Standard bruteforce, we try all the possible substitutions and return the minimum number of changes. The only things I'm vaguely proud of are the `show` tricks I've found while working on this answer.

- First of all, `mapM(:show(56^7))` is shorter than `mapM(\_->['0'..'9'])` for enumerating all the possible digits substitutions of a single number. We save 3 bytes and we gain an exponentially slower solution.
- Moreover, using `` show a`zip`show b `` instead of `zip(a>>=id)$b>>=id` saves another byte.
- With the two previous tricks, we use the `show` function often enough that defining an alias for it saves an additional byte.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>132 123</s>  120 bytes

*Saved 3 bytes by wrapping in `eval()`, as suggested by @l4m2*

Expects `(list)(n)`, where `list` is an array of strings.

```javascript
a=>n=>eval('for(m=k=1+a.join``;k--;)m=a.map(x=>s-=x.replace(/./g,j=>(d=~~i%10,t+=d!=j,i/=10,d)),s=n,i=k,t=0)|s|t>m?m:t')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fc9LboMwEAbgfU9BF5VtxYBtAoRGQw5SVYrFIzIPG4EVZRHl6gSXZkXVzUgjfTP/TCOvcipGNVhfm7Kaa5gl5Bry6io7jGoz4h5a4DsZNEbp8/nY@v6R9CCDXg74Bvnkwy0Yq6GTRYXDILzQBnJcwuOhPjijdgflOzRUhbB0JSF0Ak0VtNQCI/fpbvP@1H9aRObC6Ml0VdCZC67xF@JZjKiHlvpNcHRghHieF4aeeNtIxpwUjDu6QiejjYyEg8neuSxZoZNsI1MH@VoWzDOH/0uPUucES1938o0U/OcXEf8Gv9L/2Ckit3MfJ2t4dlhGFpnMTw)

#### Commented

This is a version without `eval()` for readability.

```javascript
a =>                        // a[] = list of positive integers, as strings
n => {                      // n = target sum
  for(                      // loop:
    m = k =                 //   start with m = k = a number higher than 10 ** p
      1 + a.join``;         //   where p is the total number of digits in a[]
    k--;                    //   stop when k = 0 (decrement it afterwards)
  )                         //
    m =                     //   update the minimum m:
      a.map(x =>            //     for each integer x in a[]:
        s -=                //       subtract from s:
          x.replace(        //         replace in x
            /./g, j => (    //         each digit j:
              d = ~~i % 10, //           extract the next digit d from i
              t += d != j,  //           increment t if d is not equal to j
              i /= 10,      //           divide i by 10
              d             //           replace j with d
            )               //
          ),                //         end of replace
          s = n,            //         start with s = copy of n,
          i = k,            //         i = copy of k
          t = 0             //         and t = 0 (counter of modified digits)
      )                     //     end of map()
      | s                   //     if s is not equal to 0
      | t > m ? m           //     or t is greater than m, leave m unchanged
              : t;          //     otherwise, update it to t
  return m                  // end of loop: return m
}                           //
```

Comment: [Warp as `eval`?](https://tio.run/##fc9LboMwEAbgfU9BF5VtxYBtAoRGQw5SVYrFIzIPG4EVZRHl6gSXZkXVzUgjfTP/TCOvcipGNVhfm7Kaa5gl5Bry6io7jGoz4h5a4DsZNEbp8/nY@v6R9CCDXg74Bvnkwy0Yq6GTRYXDILzQBnJcwuOhPjijdgflOzRUhbB0JSF0Ak0VtNQCI/fpbvP@1H9aRObC6Ml0VdCZC67xF@JZjKiHlvpNcHRghHieF4aeeNtIxpwUjDu6QiejjYyEg8neuSxZoZNsI1MH@VoWzDOH/0uPUucES1938o0U/OcXEf8Gv9L/2Ckit3MfJ2t4dlhGFpnMTw)

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 140 bytes

```javascript
n=>g=x=>x.every(t=>t.split`+`.reduce((a,b)=>a-b,n))&&1+g(x,x.map(t=>{for(i in t)for(j=10;1/t[i]&&j--;)x.push(t.slice(0,i)+j+t.slice(-~i))}))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc5BboMwEAXQfU@RFZmRsWNDCUGRWXKJKFIIcakRtRE4kauqvTqNFWVRld2M3vyv6epbPTWjHhw19qLmSs5Glq30svRM3dT4CU6Wjk1Dr92JnNioLtdGAdTxGWVZ03NsEKNIkBZ87NlHPYTA15sdQa@0WTkMYycF34uNO@hjFHWU7tGz4Tq9w7251/c@HmskHXmu9EcjfiPOjTWT7RXrbQsVpDuOcFiLIiNFtj4ivvz1h3JOEi7@Mamg2IaDNCHb14W0KILmRBCxoAnPn@1pvuRZ4EQ8/pp/AQ)

If no expression equals, replace every digit to any another and try again

Comment: @ManishKundu Fixed

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 20 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

<sup>Maybe there's a smarter way to approach this for golf?</sup>

```
D©⁵ṁḶŒp€ŒpḌS⁼ɗƇn®§§Ṃ
```

A dyadic Link accepting a list of positive integers, \$A\$, on the left and an integer, \$N\$, on the right that yields the minimal number of digit changes to make to \$A\$ that are needed to make it sum to \$N\$.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AUAAv/9qZWxsef//RMKp4oG14bmB4bi2xZJw4oKsxZJw4biMU@KBvMmXxoduwq7Cp8Kn4bmC////MTksIDcsIDIz/zIz)** Or see [all but one of the tests](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/l0MpHjVsf7mx8uGPb0UkFj5rWAMmHO3qCHzXuOTn9WHveoXWHlh9a/nBn0//Dy/WB0v//R0dHG1qa6ihYmsbqKBhbGMRy6QBFDAx0FIwMDIFCEAFjIx0FMxMg19IMzDfXUTAEIqCAoSVCh7F5LEibOVjEyBBkopFpLFcsAA) or [the other one](https://tio.run/##AUMAvP9qZWxsef//RMKp4oG14bmB4bi2xZJw4oKsxZJw4biMU@KBvMmXxoduwq7Cp8Kn4bmC////WzEyMywgNDU2Xf8xOTk4).

#### How?

```
D©⁵ṁḶp/€ŒpḌS⁼ɗƇn®§§Ṃ - Link: positive integer array A; integer N
D                    - decimal digit lists (for each of A)
 ©                   - copy that to the register for later (and yield it for now)
  ⁵                  - literal ten
   ṁ                 - mould-like (the digit lists)
    Ḷ                - lowered range (giving us [0,1,...,9] for each digit of each number in A)
       €             - for each (digit-option-list-of-lists):
     Œp              -   Cartesian product (giving us all digit lists we could make for each of A)
        Œp           - Cartesian product (giving us all lists of such possibilities)
              Ƈ      - filter by:
             ɗ       -   last three links as a dyad - f(x=that, N)
          Ḍ          -     convert (each) from base ten
           S         -     sum
            ⁼        -     equals (N)?
                ®    - recall the original digits lists of A from the register
               n     - not equal? (vectorises)
                 §   - sum of each
                  §  - sum of each
                   Ṃ - minimum
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 154 bytes

```ruby
->a,n{[0].product(*a.map{|c|[*0...10**c.to_s.size]}).select{|x|x.sum==n}.map{|c|(0...a.size).sum{|i|a[i].digits.zip(c[i+1].digits).count{|x,y|x!=y}}}.min}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYzfDoIgHEbve4q6U6LfNLPJBb0IY43QGlv@mcCmAs9OWfP2fN85o33M8Unj6SZw51jGYRj72kqTIAGtGJyXnqEMAPIMIQmmv2vQaml4SEE370Ya5yc/gbYtpV3YnGRVxO@ZrpvzygumONTqpYyGRQ2JZOqYbyQF2dtujeHZTwc6h/CNqS7EYf9kLCclJiXHRZXx3Z@cC3wprxznhFQ8fgA)

Not particularly clever: for each element of a, checks all numbers between 0 and 10^(number of digits), then filters the substitutions which yields the desired sum, and counts the digits that have changed.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 38 bytes

```
ＮθＩ⌊ＥΦＥＸχＬη⭆η⎇⁼λ,λ﹪÷ιＸχμχ⁼θΣιΣＥη¬⁼λ§ιμ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7NCsIwEITvfYrgaQMRmpOIJ/EHClYEfYFoQxvIT5tuqj59TETRvezAznw7t074mxM6xsr2AY/BXKWHga6Kk1cWYSNGhFpZZYKBWvSwVxqTI8uTuyfFS0YO0rbYQUcpI2dMwTbfO0Yu0lvhn7AbgtAjaEZmbJZMSdSuCdpBZXGrJtVIUIz8iCajeElp3p/0kOCphXp/@dRJP44O//hrrGwjH5lm6HdWMfJlsWCc8Tif9As) Very slow, so TIO can't handle arrays where the total length of digits and commas is greater than 5. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ                                      First input as a number
        χ                               Predefined variable `10`
       Ｘ                                Raised to power
          η                             Second input as a string
         Ｌ                              Length
      Ｅ                                 Map over implicit range
            η                           Second input as a string
           ⭆                            Map over characters and join
               λ                        Current character
              ⁼                         Equal to
                ,                       Literal string `,`
             ⎇                          If true then
                 λ                      Current character else
                    ι                   Outer value
                   ÷                    Integer divide
                      χ                 Predefined variable `10`
                     Ｘ                  Raised to power
                       μ                Inner index
                  ﹪                     Modulo
                        χ               Predefined variable `10`
     Φ                                  Filter strings where
                            ι           Current string
                           Σ            Sum as array of integers
                         ⁼              Equal to
                          θ             First input as a number
    Ｅ                                   Map over strings
                               η        Second input as a string
                              Ｅ         Map over characters
                                  λ     Current character
                                ¬       Is not
                                 ⁼      Equal to
                                   §ιμ  Character from string
                             Σ          Take the sum
   ⌊                                    Take the minimum
  Ｉ                                     Cast to string
                                        Implicitly print
```